Align to left in Dax format
I am trying to create a custom tooltip, using the code below. And I would like to align to the Result to the left. many thanks in advance.
measure = 
    
    VAR diffs = SWITCH(
                    TRUE(), 
                    [Week%Change@AOP24] < 0,
                    UNICHAR(10004), UNICHAR(10008))
                    //UNICHAR(9989), BLANK())
    
    VAR Result = // Need to align to the LEFT
        "CW @AOP24: " & FORMAT( [CW @AOP24], "$#,0") & UNICHAR ( 10 ) &
        "PW @AOP24: " & FORMAT( [PW @AOP24], "$#,0") & UNICHAR ( 10 ) &
        "Change @AOP24: " & FORMAT(  [CWvsPWatAOP24], "$#,0") & " (" & FORMAT([Week%Change@AOP24], "Percent") & ") " & diffs
    
    RETURN Result 


DAX doesn't control format alignment, that is done via the Visual formatting options. DAX can only do string formatting.

Alignment isn't really possible without using monospaced fonts which will be very ugly. You're better off putting the separate columns that need to be aligned in a table visual or HTML visual using a grid/flexbox/table layout and using that on a report page tooltip instead.
